# GDB disassemble for a simple program

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, gdb

Here is a simple program in C for which I used gdb to disassemble it to understand what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    printf("%d", sizeof(foo("HELLOWORLD")));
}

int foo(char* c)
{
   printf("%s\n",c);
}
```

And below is the corresponding assembly code for **disassemble main**

```
0x08048414 <+0>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048417 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x0804841a <+6>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804841d <+9>: mov    $0x8048520,%eax
   0x08048422 <+14>:    movl   $0x4,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804842a <+22>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804842d <+25>:    call   0x8048320 <printf@plt>
   0x08048432 <+30>:    leave  
   0x08048433 <+31>:    ret
```

And below is **disassemble foo**

```
0x08048434 <+0>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048435 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048437 <+3>: sub    $0x18,%esp
   0x0804843a <+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804843d <+9>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048440 <+12>:    call   0x8048330 <puts@plt>
   0x08048445 <+17>:    leave  
   0x08048446 <+18>:    ret
```

I m confused about these instructions:

1. `0x08048417 <+3>  and $0xfffffff0,%esp`
   Why stack pointer needs to be aligned when it is not modified before?
2. `0x0804841a <+6>:sub   $0x10,%esp`
   what exactly is this instruction doing particular to the program?
3. `0x0804841d <+9>:mov   $0x8048520,%eax`
   what is this instruction doing particular to the program?
4. `mov    %eax,(%esp)`
   What does parenthesis around `%esp` mean?

Would be helpful if someone explained this.

Comment: 1) align the stack, 2) reserve space on the stack, 3) address of "hello world", 4) see the calling conventions.

Comment: why exactly 16 bytes spaces?

Comment: Wrt alignment: you don't where the pointer has been before. Wrt parentheses, they are similar to `*` for C pointers.

Comment: each char takes a byte, you have 10 chars. it simply completes it to the next power of 2.

Comment: 16 bytes so it preserves the alignment?

Comment: yes. Its easier for the machine to work with aligned addresses.

Comment: but what is it storing in 0x8048520?why it requires more than 12bytes is my question?

Comment: it reads from left to right, its pretty clear by the generated code.

Comment: fairly interesting that `foo` seemed not excute? maybe because of sizeof need to be done during compile?

Comment: @ZhangYuan: `foo` is not called at all because it is used within a `sizeof` operator, and the latter is evaluated entirely at compile-time.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev you must be a assembly language guru ;)

Comment: What `-O` level did you use?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev `call   0x8048320 <printf@plt>` This part is call share library ?

Comment: @ZhangYuan: it's an address relative to the Procedure Linkage Table. This address would be "fixed up" by the OS loader to point to the actual code of `printf` from the shared library when the program is started.

Comment: [On most systems today, the stack alignment is 16 bytes (or more) to accommodate __SSE__ memory accesses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175281/what-does-it-mean-to-align-the-stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. belongs to the (function-)prologue, it is aligning the SP to a 16-byte boundary, by bitmasking the SP.
2. memory for the stack-frame is created, as your pointer needs to be passed to the function. The address will be passed from the stack to the function. Yet it seems that the expression is evluated at compile-time, so no need for the actual call.
3. `0x8048520` is probably the adress of your string "%d". It is being put into eax, from there on it is put on the stack using the stackpointer.

There is plenty of material around, like [this](https://www.hackerschool.com/blog/7-understanding-c-by-learning-assembly).

Comment: but as the function foo is not called(there is no call instruction in main)why Hello world is added to stack..and is it necessary to align SP everytime new function is called?

Comment: @bash.d: It is not the address of "HELLOWORLD", but most likely the address of the printf format string. `foo` is not called at all since the whole `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile-time to `4`.

Comment: address of printf is 0x0804832b

Comment: @vindhya: The `and` operation with the stack pointer "rounds it down" to the closest 16-byte boundary. Putting data at such boundaries enables the computer to fetch and process that data more efficiently.

Comment: Not all of the 16bytes are actually used. The stack is used to pass arguments from one function to another. The calling function assigns space on the stack (creating a stack-frame) and the callee (the function that is called), can access the arguments from the stack.

Comment: @ Blagovest Buyukliev:thanks.COuld you please clarify one more thing i could not understand..what does 0x8048520 has?

Comment: @vindhya: it is the address of the string `"%d"`.

Comment: @bash.d:And one more thing. could you please explain why value from %eax is moved to space pointed to %esp?

Comment: @vindhya This what you could call "putting it on the stack". As the stack is a contiguous area of memory you can't put anything "on" it literally, but this is how it works.

Comment: @bash.d:so do you mean address 0x8048520 cannot be added directly to %esp as in mov $0x8048520,(%esp) ?

Comment: This depends on the OS, I guess. Some OS's use the registers (eax, ebx, ecx, edx) to pass arguments. But this would require the registers to be saved first using push-instructions. Using SP is more "convenient" and allows (technically) many, many arguments to be passed.

Comment: @bash.d:why cant address 0x8048520 cannot be added directly to %esp as in mov $0x8048520?

Comment: @vindhya: I suppose the compiler wants to "at least leave something" in `eax` since you do not have a `return` statement and the function returns `int`. Normally the `eax` register would be used for the return value, but in this case it is absent.

Comment: @ Blagovest Buyukliev:ok..thanks for your insight..but just for confirmation we can use mov $0x8048520,(%esp) right?

Comment: @vindhya: Yes, a "smarter" compiler would do that.