# Writing assembly Language in C

Tags: c, assembly

I am writing assembly language in C. I was given the following assembly code:

```
fn:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $1, -4(%ebp)
    jmp    .f2
.f3:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    imull   8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    subl    $1, 8(%ebp)
.f2:
    cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
     jg        .f3
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    ret
```

I have written my code in C below:

```
     fn (int x)
     { 
         int y = 1;

         if(x  > 1):
              int z = y *=   x
              x – 1;

         return z;
```

}

Can someone tell me if I am on the right track with my C code? or if I am off and if I am can you point me in the right direction.
Thank You in advanced

Comment: There is clearly a loop going on here.

Comment: Is that supposed to be valid C? (Because it is not, for several reasons.)

Comment: can you please explain where you see a loop? I am confused and looking for help

Comment: At `jmp f2` you begin a `while(x > 1)` loop. Do you see how it loops?

Comment: You have a backwards conditional branch `jg .f3`.  Pretty much ANY backwards branch in the asm code is a loop.  Exactly what kind of loop depends on other things.

Comment: oh. okay I see what you mean, thank you for clarifying

Comment: "Rewrite this code" generally isn't an on-topic question.  If you have specific questions about what some assembly is doing, we'd be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
fn:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
```

This is the usual function startup used in the [calling convertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) `__cdecl`, save existing `%ebp` to the stack then save `%esp` (current stack address) to `%ebp`. `%ebp` will be from now on the reference to the stack call point of this function used by the assembly code to access both parameters and local variables. To conclude this function, the opposite will be done in the future, as well as setting the "return" value to `%eax`.

At this point you can assume `%ebp` points to the current stack position where the previous `%ebp` is stored, `%ebp + 4` is the function's return point, and everything from `%ebp + 8` on is the data of the function parameters. Negative values will be accessing unused stack space, where the function can store it's local variables.

```
    subl    $16, %esp
```

This is reserving 22 bytes of information in the stack for local variables. It can be 22 variables of 1 byte or 1 variable of 22 bytes, there is no way to know. It can reserve unused bytes to make [stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175281/what-does-it-mean-to-align-the-stack).

Its important to change the value of `%esp` at this point so any call to `push`, `pop` and `call` won't overwrite this function's local variables.

```
    movl    $1, -4(%ebp)
```

Here it is possible to assume that the first of the local variables present in this function is a 32-bits integer at the address `%ebp - 4`. It's value was just set to 1. Lets call this variable `i`.

```
    jmp    .f2
.f3:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    imull   8(%ebp), %eax
```

Based on what this `imull` is doing we can assume the function takes at least one parameter at the address `%ebp + 8`, and it seems its a 32-bits integer being multiplied by `i`. Lets call this parameter `x`.

```
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
```

So far we can assume `i = x * i`.

```
    subl    $1, 8(%ebp)
```

And now `x = x - 1`.

```
.f2:
    cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
     jg        .f3
```

Here we are checking if `x` is greater than 1. If true, jumps to `f3`, that is a backward jump therefore it seems we have a loop going on.

```
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Here outside the loop we see it set `%eax` to `i` and terminate the function, we can interpret it as `return i`.

Compiling the analyzed information together, we can assume the original function must have looked somewhat like this:

```
int fn(int x)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (x > 1)
    {
        i = i * x; // or just i *= x, same thing
        x = x - 1; // or just x--, same thing
    }
    return i;
}
```